# What method should I use to cluster small data set?

Tags: clustering, validation, small-sample, hierarchical-clustering, methodology

I would like to cluster a small data sets [23 genes, 50 samples], but I don't know what method I should use... could you give me any recommendation?

I have applied hierarchical clustering (Wards method and euclidian distance) and it does a really good job, but I would like to know if this approximation is correct. Also, there is a way to validate this clustering or to confirm the number of clusters I should get? I have tried pvclust package...but I don't know if I should use other method to determine the number of clusters (k-means, WGCNA)

I am interested in clustering both, genes and samples. These gene expression data has been obtained by qPCR and refered, but I don't know if I should scale samples anyway.

I am starting to learn these type of analysis and R now... so I really appreciate your help!!

Thanks a lot!!!

**MORE DETAILS**

This is part of my data:

[image: Raw data.]

Columns are genes and raws are samples. I am worried because there are some values that are really high, but I don't want to eliminate them because they are the most positive samples...I am using "scale" with these data (>mydata <- scale(mydata)). I am also eliminating all the samples with an empty data in some gene (>mydata <- na.omit(mydata) )

After this, I used the dendogram to cluster genes:

> d <- dist(mydata, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
>   fit <- hclust(d, method="ward.D2")
>   plot(fit) # display dendogram

This was the result:
[image: Ward and euclidian hierarchical clustering]

However, I don't know what is the point where I should cut to define the number of clusters in a significative way.

I have tried different strategies, with really bad results, but I am not sure if these measures can be applied to my data properly (considering the number of data or the presence of outliers):

> library("factoextra")
>   fviz_nbclust(my_data, kmeans, method = "gap_stat")

[image]

> fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method='silhouette')

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have also used this:

> get_clust_tendency(my_data, n = 22, gradient = list(low = "steelblue",  high = "white"))

$hopkins_stat
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWmgg.png) **0.6069425**

[image]

I have also used pvclust, but again I am not sure if it is correct to use it.
[image]

**To summarize, I would like to use one method (or a combination of several methods):
- good for small gene data set
- with small influence of outliers
- which allows to get an stadistic significance or something to help to decide the number of proper clusters**

I would really appreciate any suggestions and if you could confirm if anything that I have applied is correct or not.

Thanks again!!!

Comment: euclidean + ward is ok.. when using euclidean, the samples / genes with higher values will weigh more, so for example, if one gene is expressed 5x on average than the rest, the clustering will depend a lot of this gene

Comment: yeah.. what you have in the question is quite vague. If you provide data and also some plots maybe you get suggestions on whether it's ok

Comment: Thanks StupidWolf! I have edited my question because I think that my approach is not being ok with these data....